# When the homsets of a category are structured.

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, category-theory

If the objects of a category are algebraic structures in their own right, this often places additional structure on the homsets. Is there somewhere I can learn more about this general idea?

---

**Example 1.** Let $\cal M$ denote the category of magmas and **functions**, not necessarily structure-preserving. Then given objects $X$ and $Y$ of $\cal M$, the hom"set" $\mathrm{Hom}(X,Y)$ is probably best viewed as a *magma* as opposed to a set, with the pointwise operation inherited from $Y$. Furthermore we have a right (but not left) distributivity law. In particular, given objects $X, Y$ and $Z$ and arrows $f:X \rightarrow Y$ and $g,g' : Y \rightarrow Z,$

$$(g+g')\circ f = (g \circ f) + (g' \circ f).$$

**Example 2.** Now let $\cal N$ denote the category of [medial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_magma) magmas and magma **homomorphisms**. Then given objects $X$ and $Y$ of $\cal N$, the hom"set" $\mathrm{Hom}(X,Y)$ can be viewed as a medial magma in its own right. Furthermore, we have both left and right distributivity laws. In the sense that given objects $X, Y$ and $Z$ and arrows $f,f':X \rightarrow Y$ and $g,g' : Y \rightarrow Z,$

$$(g+g')\circ f = (g \circ f) + (g' \circ f)$$

$$g \circ (f + f') = (g \circ f) + (g \circ f').$$

Comment: This is the notion of a category enriched over a monoidal category. "Enriched category" will work as a good search term; there's even a short chapter on them in Mac Lane.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine, I've been looking over the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enriched_category) page dedicated to enriched categories for the past half hour or so before asking this question, but honestly I cannot see the connection. What have monoidal categories got to do with anything?

Comment: @user18921 A monodical category have a operation $\otimes$ which can emulate the composition. Imagine you don't have such an $\otimes$ : what could it means to compose arrows (what even is an arrow when $\hom(a,b)$ is an abstract object of a category) in the enriched category ?

Comment: @Pece, still not getting it. Why is $\mathrm{hom}(a,b)$ an abstract object of a category? For example, if $a$ and $b$ are magmas, well $\mathrm{hom}(a,b)$ should also denote some kind of magma. Magmas have elements, so that isn't very abstract.

Comment: Monoidal categories are those with just enough structure to define "identity morphisms" and "composition of Hom sets" in a generalized way. As for deeper reasons why some categories are naturally enriched categories, often self-enriched, I can't say anything useful. But it seems to be the notion you're going for.

Comment: If you have a [commutative algebraic theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/commutative+algebraic+theory), then the category of models has a canonical monoidal closed structure.

Comment: @ZhenLin, can you explain a little how monoidal closed categories come into it? Obviously if $\mathcal{C}$ is a category of models for a commutative algebraic theory, then every hom-set of $\mathcal{C}$ can itself be viewed as a model; and for every operation $T$ of airity $n$ we have left and right distributivity over composition, as in: $T(f_0,\cdots,f_{n-1}) \circ g = T(f_0 \circ g,\cdots,f_{n-1} \circ g).$ Okay, but how does that relate to monoidal closed categories?

Comment: It is not enough to say that the hom-sets are structured: that in itself can happen for trivial reasons, e.g. sets equipped with a $G$-action where $G$ is a fixed group. So we must also relate the structure to the category somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be my humble attempt to answer "why enriched, why monoidal?"

So in a general category, we can just view the $Hom$-objects as being sets, the monoidal operation being the Cartesian product, and the "unit" is any terminal object. It seems trivial to note, but the composition operation out of $Hom(A,B)\times Hom(B,C)$ is a morphism in the category of sets, while the Cartesian product is also a set.

This observation becomes less trivial when we move to, say, Abelian groups or categories as $Hom$-objects. What we have in, say, $\mathbf{Cat}$ is not just a category structure on the $Hom$ objects, but the composition operation that maps $B^A\times C^B$ to $C^A$ is itself *functorial*. The trivial category is obviously a unit for the product operation in $\mathbf{Cat}$, and functors from it can pick out the identity functor in any category $A^A$, which is the endofunctor of $A$ that acts as a unit in the composition operation.

That's the point about monoidal categories. There are lots of arbitrary structures you could add to a $Hom$-set, but not every category's composition operation will respect that structure in an appropriate way. Further, not every category has the right structure for its objects to be the $Hom$-objects of a category. If you diagram out how the composition operation works in $\mathbf{Set}$, then you can see it's exactly the kind of structure that a category's being monoidal makes possible. And enrichment is the condition that composition respects the additional $Hom$ structure in the appropriate way.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the notion of an [enriched category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/enriched+category). A good reference is [Kelly's book](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/10/tr10abs.html). For example, the category of medial magmas is monoidal and closed, hence enriched over itsself. Your example of magmas doesn't fit to this picture, basically because it is a little bit unnatural to consider all functions as morphisms.